# problema al enviar un array por metodo onclick, muestra undefined

Tags: javascript, array

Buenos dias a todos, tengo un problema al enviar un array por un metodo "onclick" al querer mostrar el array enviado me sale "undefined"

codigo del onclick:

```js
firebase.database().ref("/4/").on("value", (dataSnapshot) => {
    dataSnapshot.forEach(function(item){
      var valor = item.val();
      var td = document.createElement('tr');
      var detalle = valor.detail;
      var arrayFinal = []
      for(var i in detalle){
          arrayFinal[i] = detalle[i];
      }
      console.log(arrayFinal);
      td.innerHTML = "<td>" + valor.nombre + "</td>" +" <td> <paper-button class='btn btn-primary' onclick=\"modal("+ arrayFinal +")\" raised> detalle  </paper-button></td>" + "<td>" + valor.valor + " <span class='text-danger'>  CL$ </span></td>";
      document.getElementById("ascap").appendChild(td);
  });
});
```

codigo del metodo al cual el onclick llama " modal() "

```js
function modal(results){
   console.log(typeof(results));
   var newArray = JSON.stringify(results);
   console.log(results);
 };
```

impresion de la variable arrayFinal:

> [detalle: "string", fechaDoc: "date", fechaPag: "date", montoDecl:
>   "number", montoTotDoc: "number"…]

respuesta en consola de la funcion modal():

> my-home.html:480 undefined my-home.html:482 undefined

he intentado hacer el JSON.stringify antes de enviarlo, pero al momento de imprimir devuelve un arreglo vacio "{}"

¿alguna idea, en que me equivoco?

Comment: lo que colocas como `impresion de la variable arrayFinal:` no es un arrays (u objeto) valido, sin embargo en el ejemplo que te deje lo he colocado como un objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes pegar un objeto como tal en código ***html***, en tu caso que tienes un ***JSON*** debes usar la propiedad `JSON.stringify()` para convertirlo a ***string*** y de esta manera lo podrás pegar, Ejemplo:

```js
firebase.database().ref("/4/").on("value", (dataSnapshot) => {
    dataSnapshot.forEach(function(item){
      var valor = item.val();
      var td = document.createElement('tr');
      var detalle = valor.detail;
      var arrayFinal = []
      for(var i in detalle){
          arrayFinal[i] = detalle[i];
      }
      console.log(arrayFinal);
      td.innerHTML = "<td>" + valor.nombre + "</td>" +" <td> <paper-button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='modal("+ JSON.stringify(arrayFinal) +")' raised> detalle  </paper-button></td>" + "<td>" + valor.valor + " <span class='text-danger'>  CL$ </span></td>";
      document.getElementById("ascap").appendChild(td);
  });
});
```

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo funcional de como debes hacerlo:

```js
function modal(results){
 console.log(typeof(results));
 console.log(results);
 };

arrayFinal = {detalle: "string", fechaDoc: "date", fechaPag: "date", montoDecl: "number", montoTotDoc: "number"}

console.log(arrayFinal);

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML="<button onclick='modal("+ JSON.stringify(arrayFinal) +")'>funcion modal()</button>";
```

Espero esto te sirva, Saludos ;))

Comment: al hacerlo así se envia pero al querer imprimir la variable que recibo me imprime un [] vacío

Comment: te deje un ejemplo funcional de como debes hacerlo.

Comment: noto en tu código que escapas las comillas dobles \", esto causa que `JSON.stringify()` no escape las comillas dobles que coloca al convertir un **objeto en string**, te sugiero uses en su lugar las comillas simples ', de hecho las usas en `class='...'`

Comment: solucionado!!  muchas gracias, aparte de lo de las comillas simples el error estaba en que al momento de iniciar la variable lo hacia con [] "var variable = [] " lo cambie por " var variable = {} " y ya pude imprimir todo el arreglo, muchas gracias <3

Comment: me contenta que hayas solucionado, y recuerda calificar la respuesta que mas se ajuste a una solución al problema planteado, Saludos!! ;))...